# Apple Watch sends texts to wrong person

Tags: messages, apple-watch

My Apple Watch Sport recently has decided to send all messages targeted at one person to a different person. No matter how I send messages to person A (i.e. respond to their texts, send through the friends interface, etc.) they are always sent to person B. I've tried to reboot the watch and my iPhone but no success.

Comment: Are the two people connected at all?

Comment: Specifically, are they on the same Apple ID?

Comment: They have no connection to each other and have no shared Apple ID. One is using an iPhone 6 and the other a Nexus 5. They have different names, phone numbers, email addresses, etc. The only similarity is that they are the 2 people I text with the most.

Comment: Have you tried to unpair the  Watch and re-pair it again?

Comment: @bjbk: yes I did

Comment: One more question, did you try removing the friend(s) using the My Watch app on your iPhone then re-adding them?

Comment: Do the messages show for the right contact on your phone?

Comment: I did try removing and adding them again which did not work. I tried repairing again and it worked though!

Comment: Did anyone find a solution as mine is doing the same :(

Comment: Repairing the devices worked.